# Orden de argumentos de getopt() en C

Tags: c, linux

Necesito usar dos argumentos con un parámetro cada uno, solo que en caso de agruparlos el parámetro sirve para los dos argumentos.

Por ejemplo:

```
miprograma -a 45

miprograma -b 45

miprograma -ab 45
```

No se si se entiende, ya probe con:

```
getopt (argc, argv, "ab:")

getopt (argc, argv, "ab:a:b:")
```

y no funcionan, desde ya agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Como puedo lograr lo que necesito?

Comment: Yo creo que con getopt no lo vas a conseguir porque entiende el argumento como un único carácter. Revisa el manual de getopt_long, que permite que el argumento sea de mas de un carácter (cuando se utiliza -- por delante del argumento). Aún con getopt_long no creo que consigas que escribiendo un solo argumento multicaracter lo puedas asociar a varios argumentos. Con lo cual, la única solución que veo es o bien no usar el getopt y tratar manualmente los argumentos argc y argv del main, o bien usar el getopt  pero en la invocación poner por ejemplo miprograma -a 45 -b 45

Answer (score 1):

primero que nada muchas gracias a todos los que colaboraron.
Logre implemetar lo que necesitaba usando getopt() con un orden distinto en la Mascara que uso para parsear.
En vez de usar este orden:

```
getopt (argc, argv, "ab:a:b:")
```

implemente la mascara en este orden:

```
getopt (argc, argv, "a:b:ab")
```

y funciona según lo esperado, ingresando un solo argumento con un solo parámetro e ingresando los dos argumentos y una sola vez el parametro. Funcionan estas 3 convinaciones:

```
miprograma -a 45

miprograma -b 45

miprograma -ab 45
```

Saludos.

Comment: Con `a:b:` creo que alcanza.